# Python Decimal too many digits

Tags: python, python-decimal

I tried creating a temperature converter below:

```py
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 10

celsius = Decimal(12)
fahrenheit = celsius*9/5+32
kelvin = celsius+Decimal(273.15)
romer = celsius*21/40+Decimal(7.5)
```

When converted to a string, `fahrenheit` returns `53.6` and `romer` returns `13.8`, both with no additional decimal places. However, `kelvin` returns `285.1500000`. (This isn't even `285.1500001`). How do I make sure it returns just enough places, i.e. `285.15`? I assume it is not a problem with adding floating decimals because `romer` is fine.

Comment: What is `precision`? Make this a running script including the print showing the output.

Comment: `Decimal(273.15)` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: You should initialize `Decimal` with strings (e.g., `Decimal("273.15")`) and avoid doing floating point math with python integers (`9/5` should be `Decimal("9")/Decimal("5")`), etc... But mostly, you should make this a fully running example, including display of the result, and let us know whats wrong. Note, this is what I asked 2 hours ago. Lets make this a good question!

Answer (score 0):

Do simple

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 10

celsius = Decimal(12)
fahrenheit = celsius*9/5+32
kelvin = round(celsius+Decimal(273.15), 2) #if you need more then 2 digit replace 2 with other number
romer = celsius*21/40+Decimal(7.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, you can use the built in `round()` function. It takes in two params, the number required to be rounded and the number of decimals to be rounded.

```
kelvin = round(celsius+Decimal(273.15), 2)
```

Here `285.1500000` will be rounded to 2 decimal place `285.15`. Other method like `str.format()`, `trunc()`, `round_up()`, etc are also available.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use `str.format()`. For example:

```
formatted_kelvin = "{:.2f}". format(kelvin)
```

So, if you printed this, it would print only 2 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks! However, it wouldn't work properly if the actual answer contains more decimal places.